# How to get Json Data from MongoDB against a specific User who posted it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
router.post('/',auth, async (req, res) => {

const { error } = validate(req.body); //Error Check
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let property = new Property({  //Creating Object: Property as per defined Schema:
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    price: req.body.price,

    user: {
      _id: req.user._id, //Getting the ID from auth middleware with JWT Token Authenticared
    }
  });
  console.log({property});
  await property.save(); //Saving the Object
  
  res.send(property); //Displaying User with created Object i.e. Property
});
```

I'm Creating a Property using POST Method.

Now I want to Get the Data from MongoDB, but only for the user who's currently logged in and created that data.

```
  //Writing a GET METHOD to List of Properties with Valid Token:
router.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
  try{
  
  //Getting the Information of User by the current user.id loggin in: ... .select('-password') sets it to don't show password
  const property = await Property.findById(req.user );
  res.send(property);
  }
  
  catch (ex){
      console.error(ex.message);
  }
  });
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the actual Property model schema definition? I take it the `user` field is a ref to the `User` model i.e. `{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }` ?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `findById`try `find({user: req.user._id})`.

`req.user` contains the authenticated user's information so by using `_id` we can get can the ID which helps us filter the Properties created by a Specific User